# How might I implement this into C++?

Tags: c++

So, I'm having some issues here implementing this math problem in C++.

Let's say I have a game that involves two randomly generated outcomes, these outcomes can either be a win or loss.

The algorithm is explained here: http://imageshack.us/f/98/terriblyexplained.png/

For example, if the first six rounds of the game go win, loss, win, win, loss, loss, the odds of winning the 7th round of that would be 78.90625%, and the odds of losing would be 21.09375%.

How might I implement this scenario into a formula, and implement that into an algorithm I can run in C++?

Comment: Step 1: By actually trying to write it.  Step 2: Asking the Q here, at the point where you get stuck.

Comment: How did you calculate that the odds of winning in the sample scenario are 78.9%?

Comment: Are the two outcomes statistically independent? Nothing in your specification says that the odds of winning is dependent on previous games, or that it'll always be 78.90625 out of 100. Your current specification is not precise enough to even begin to start implementing it.

Comment: @In silico  The outcomes are partially independent, the results don't directly rely upon each other, but they're based on the order they're found in. Since there were losses prior to it, and wins prior to the losses, its represented statistically to expect a greater chance at a win.

Comment: @Jacob: Surely you know exactly how they are "partially independent". I find it odd that you ask how to implement the above scenario into a formula, and yet you come to an actual, concrete probability of 0.7890625 for winning the 7th game after "win, loss, win, win, loss, loss". That implies that you at least know how the probability values are to be calculated. Edit your question to include the actual calculation and we might be able to help you.

Comment: Ah, yes, perhaps this can explain?  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/98/terriblyexplained.png/

Comment: The image in the link is unreadable in my browser. If you want help here you have to do some work yourself. This means at a minimum, clearly explaining your problem, showing your attempts to solve your problem, asking specific questions. 'Please write my code for me' doesn't cut it I'm afraid.

Comment: @Jacob maybe it's a new kind of math I still don't know, but how something can be "partially independent"? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29

Comment: @ybungalobill: The OP probably isn't aware that independence is a rigorously defined concept in probability theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    double WinChance = 0.5;
    double LossChance = 0.5;

    std::string result;
    while(std::cin >> result)
    {
       if(result == "Win")
       {
           WinChance /= 2.0;
           LossChance = 1.0 - WinChance;
       }
       else
       {
           LossChance /= 2.0;
           WinChance = 1.0 - LossChance;
       }
    }

    std::cout << "Winning Chance next round is " << WinChance  * 100.0 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Losing  Chance next round is " << LossChance * 100.0 << std::endl;
}
```

Instead of inputting the result you can generate it randomly according to current `WinChance`. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

So you know the exact mathematical procedure, what is your question about?

So as not to store winning and losing probability separately:

```
double nextWinProbability(double winProb, bool lastWasWin) 
{

    if (lastWasWin) {
        return winProb / 2;
    }
    else {
       return 50 + winProb / 2; // = 100 - loseProb / 2 = 100 - (100 - winProb) / 2 
    }
}
```

You might as well represent probabilities not as percentages, but as a value between 0.0 and 1.0.